# version of ldap installed - one liner

Tags: ldap, solaris

I am using LDAP which is installed in a solaris machine. To check the version of LDAP i go to /ldap and check the version installed as if it is version 5 then there is a directory of the name v5.0 and so on. After getting into the directory i check the directory structure.

Can anybody tell me is there any shortest way or one liner to check the version of ldap installed in my machine?

Answer (score 1):

The correct method is to query the [root DSE](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/the-root-dse-is-that-entry-with-zero-rdns-and-contains-information-about-the-directory-server/). According to **[RFC3045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3045)**, clients should query the root DSE for `vendorName` and `vendorVersion`. For more general information about the root DSE, see **[this blog entry](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/the-root-dse-is-that-entry-with-zero-rdns-and-contains-information-about-the-directory-server/)**.

By way of example, a client could query the root DSE like this:

```
ldapsearch --hostname hostname --port port \
    --searchScope base --baseDn '' '(&)' vendorName vendorVersion
```

If you use the older OpenLDAP version of ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port \
     -s base -b '' '(&)' vendorName vendorVersion
```

Note that the information in the root DSE might be restricted, that is, subject to access control.

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris, check out the "pkginfo" command, or try "ldapsearch -V"

Comment: pkginfo is giving me the following output
     ERROR: information for "ldap" was not found
although ldap is installed in the machine

Comment: For ldapsearch -V i am getting the following help from man pages and it is not giving me the desired esult:

 -V version

         Specify the LDAP protocol version number to be used  for
         the  delete  operation,  either  2  or 3. LDAP v3 is the
         default. Specify LDAP v2 when connecting to servers that
         do not support v3.

Comment: going the `pkginfo` route, something like this `ls /var/sadm/pkg/| grep -i ldap | xargs pkginfo -x` will give you the name and version of all package names containing "ldap" - at least those installed via the Solaris pkg system.